# Loading scripts from custom plugin in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, plugins

I have this in my main plugin file (/plugins/oglasi/oglasi.php)

```
<?php
 /*
 Plugin Name: Oglasi
 Plugin URI: 
 Description: Custom post type "Oglasi".
 Version: 1.0
 Author: Dragi
 Author URI:
 License: GPLv2
 */

function james_adds_to_the_head() {
    wp_register_script( 'add-bx-js', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/filter-oglasi.js', array('jquery'),'',true  ); 
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'james_adds_to_the_head' );
```

And here /plugins/oglasi/js/filter-oglasi.js I have:

```
jquery(document).ready(function() {

    console.log("MAIN IS LOADED");
    alert("Dragi");
});
```

but it is not working. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

`wp_register_script()` registers a script to be enqueued later using the `wp_enqueue_script()` function. Use `wp_enqueue_script('add-bx-js')` to load registered script. This means, if you want to register your scripts, but not directly load them in your pages, you can register the files once, and then load them when you need them.

Use the following code :

```
function james_adds_to_the_head() {
    wp_register_script( 'add-bx-js', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/filter-oglasi.js', array('jquery'),'',true  ); 
    wp_enqueue_script( 'add-bx-js' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'james_adds_to_the_head' );
```

or :

```
function james_adds_to_the_head() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'add-bx-js', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/filter-oglasi.js', array('jquery'),'',true  );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'james_adds_to_the_head' );
```

more info :

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/82490/when-should-i-use-wp-register-script-with-wp-enqueue-script-vs-just-wp-enque

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_register_script/

**Update**

You have error in your js file. Use `jQuery` instead of `jquery` as follow and then use `CTRL+F5` to force refresh browser cache. Also you can use `wp_register_script()` fourth parameter - version parameter - to force refresh assets.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    console.log("MAIN IS LOADED");
    alert("Dragi");
});
```

Comment: Sorry, but it is still not working. I still can see the message in the console, or the alert. This can work if a put the code in the theme's functions.php file, but I want to do this in the plugin. Any other thought? Thank you.

Comment: `wp_enqueue_script()` works in both themes and plugins. Check your browser console for 404 or 403 error and search your file name in browser page source.

Comment: Check answer update. Code tested and works properly.